# Setting toastr opacity?

Tags: toastr

Is there any way to change it?  I tried defining the toastClass as a class with opacity set to 1, but saw no changes:

```
.toast-style{
   opacity: 1;
}

toastr.options.toastClass = 'toast-style';
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No JavaScript required for this. You should be able to change this in CSS using either

```
#toast-container > div {
    opacity:1;
}
```

or

```
.toast {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Good solution for most cases. But is it possible to do this on a per-toast-message basis? Imagine most uses of the `toastr` call on a page are fine transluscent - but if the user does that special thing, we want to show it loud and proud (opaque) and wait for them to close it.

Comment: `!important` is almost always evil

Comment: Note that if the second option is used(.toast) you will lose fade in and fade out effects! The solution is the first bit of code, but if you have trouble getting this to override the default library css priority I suggest you do something like 
body #toast-container > div {
    opacity: 1;
}

This should allow you to maintain your fade effects and keep a bright shinning notification.

Comment: Very useful for ngx-toastr package for Angular which does not work if you don't do this

Comment: @DanielFilipe Thank you! I was wondering why my fade was gone when I tried to make my toastr solid...

Comment: We should be able to set the opacity in the `toastr.options{..}`.  Depending where the toast message is displayed, it sometimes blends in with the background.  I want ALL the messages 100% completely opaque - no transparency.

Answer (score 6):

```
#toast-container > div {
   opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

[Test Working Example;](http://jsfiddle.net/__Angelina/o275o0q4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this for a single toastr so went this route:

```
toastr.options = {
    ... 
};

toastr.info(
    'All of my favorite singers have stolen all of my best lines',
    'The Title'
);

$('#toast-container').addClass('nopacity');
```

...and then...

```
#toast-container.nopacity > div {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to decrease opacity, they can do something like this:

```
.toast-error { background-color: rgba(255,111,105,0.7) !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying all the CSS from "~ngx-toastr/toastr.css" into the application's styles.css file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If u are not able to see toast notification after setting opacity ten you have to check CSS configuration in angular.json file of your project. Just like:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss",
  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css" // try adding '../' if you're using angular cli before 6
]
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using bootstrap 4.6, setting opacity did not help.
but setting `background-color: white` for the **toast-body** did the job.

> you on also use bg-light etc. on **toast-body**

hopes this help somebody!