# ngx-toastr, Toast not showing in Angular 7

Tags: angular, toastr

I'm currently developing a web app using Angular 7. I wanted to include ngx-toastr to send notifications to users but it isn't working as expected. When I trigger a toast nothing happens, except for a box in the size of a toast is appearing in bottom right corner but only when hovered over by the coursor.
Following an example of how I trigger the toastr function. Test is invoked by the click of a button.

```
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-action-controls',
  templateUrl: './action-controls.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./action-controls.component.scss']
})
export class Notification implements OnInit {
  test(){   
          this.toast.success("I'm a toast!", "Success!");
  }
 constructor(private toast: ToastrService) { }
}
```

I includet the library css files in the angular.json file in my project like this:

```
     ...        
     "styles": [
        "src/styles.scss",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
      ],
      ...
```

And like this in my app.module.ts file:

```
...
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ToastrModule} from 'ngx-toastr';
...
  imports: [
    ...
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 1000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
    })
   ]
...
```

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, has anyone had similar experiences?

Comment: Hope this answer would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940941/unable-to-display-toast-message-in-angular-5

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have come a little further. Now the toast is rendered correctly, but still only displayed when you hover your mouse over it.

Comment: That could be because of your custom css. upvote the answer if it helped

Comment: I fixed it by  adding @import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css'; into style.css

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I was able to make a minimal reproduction of your issue, and I don't see any problems:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avcidu

Is it possible that you have some custom styles that conflict with the toastr.css styles, or a template that is malformed (an unclosed div, for example)?

Are you using the latest version of ngx-toastr? (9.1.1 at the time of this post)

What does your template look like?

## Update:

The previous stackblitz now shows the replicated problem. Here is the link again: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avcidu

Looks like both bootstrap and ngx-toastr use the .toastr class, affecting the opacity property on the toastr div.

This thread has a workable answer: [Setting toastr opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635655/setting-toastr-opacity#answer-17640150)

The answer therein is to force the opacity to 1. Add this your custom stylesheet:

```
#toast-container > div {
    opacity:1;
}
```

And here's the working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjazzq

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. I looked through all my templates and found no errors.  Even with a minimal component like the one I wrote in my initial post, I didn't succeed.
I'm also sure that it's not related to my css or scss files, because I have only a few styles that don't seem to be related to the problem.
Is it possible that it is related to other libraries I use, for example bootstrap?

Comment: There's a naming collison for the .toastr CSS class in boostrap and ngx-toastr. See: 'getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts'. Also note my updated answer. Please mark as correct if it solves the problem adequately.

Comment: Thank you so much this made the deal, now it works perfectly!

Comment: Note that for `positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'`, it doesn't do a very good job though...

Comment: @dstj In what way? The opacity remains unbroken in that configuration. The OP's specific problem was the opacity. Is there a different problem?

Comment: @KeenanDiggs, yes it makes it visible, but it's not "full width" as before Bootstrap 4.2.1. I forked your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b18xmd)

Comment: Here's the link to Bootstrap 4.2.1 [issue on the ngx-toastr repo](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/602)

Comment: @KeenanDiggs Thanks a lot man !! I was scratching my head where is the root casue of the issue ??

Comment: Wouldn't have find this so fast without your answer!

Comment: wow!!!!! if I wouldn't see this, I would have been digging another 3 hours and pulling out my last a few hair on my head! Thanks man!

Comment: working great for me. i am looking for the solution since 3 days. i am thinking that there is a problem in importing toastr module but this is a issue of css. thank you..

Comment: If you're using SASS, just don't import "~bootstrap/scss/toasts" assuming you have no need for Bootstrap's toast alongside ngx-toastr.  Should also avoid any further conflicts until ngx-toastr addresses this.

Comment: not working for me, apparently, the css mention background propertiess, but no color, adding a background:somecolor works, so the problem must come from toast itself (.ts)

Comment: On safari I notice it periodically won't render until I click on something else in the UI like a dropdown or another animation.  Might be a issue with Angular's animation module though.

Answer (score 40):

When reading through this thread, I guess you could fix your problem. However, I would leave the solution to my problem here unless someone might have the same as us.

What I have done to fix the problem is: to add `@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';`  into `style.css` under the root directory of the project will get rid of the issue.

Comment: Your solution worked for me and I should also add that you don't need to add the styles into `angular.json`. Once your global `styles.scss` imports the toastr css library, everything should just work.

Answer (score 17):

Even after adding the opacity css code from the above answers in my global style.scss, it did not solve my problem entirely; I was getting a blank white box.

After adding the additional css mentioned in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/605#issuecomment-452467680), the toasts are working correctly.

The relevant code from the above post is below:

```
/* TOASTR BUGFIX */
#toast-container > div {
  opacity: 1;
}
.toast {
  font-size: initial !important;
  border: initial !important;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0) !important;
}
.toast-success {
  background-color: #51A351 !important;
}
.toast-error {
  background-color: #BD362F !important;
}
.toast-info {
  background-color: #2F96B4 !important;
}
.toast-warning {
  background-color: #F89406 !important;
}
```

Comment: more like "toasty-type-error..." in the last versions

Answer (score 6):

This is deeply linked to the new bootstrap version that comes with Toasts.
Here is an issue discussing it :

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2945

I myself did keep the "old" 4.1.3 bootstrap, and will keep an eye on next ng-bootstrap version, that way I don't hack the css :)

```
#toast-container > div {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: The opacity 1 trick works but the background color of my toasts were white. To fix this you can use this additional CSS:

    .toast-error {
      background-color: #BD362F !important;
    }
    
    .toast-success {
      background-color: #51A351 !important;
    }

Comment: Exactly, that's not a big deal indeed but I often loose track of such a fix, that's why I prefer not to :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, It was due to a **conflict between some CSS**. I overwrote that CSS by simply **importing the styles of ngx-toastr** in `styles.css`

**styles.scss**

**@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';**

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is 3 months old but just to inform everyone of the latest changes. ngx-toastr v10.0.2 no longer has this bug with bootstrap v4.2.1

So updating your ngx-toastr should fix this issue. It did for me :)

https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/releases

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to [Keenan Diggs' answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989699/2545439) is providing an additional style class in the ToastrModule definition which sets opacity to 1. IMO this is a bit more clear what we're trying to achieve here and also doesn't have to depend on #toast-container.

app.module.ts:

```
ToastrModule.forRoot({
  toastClass: 'toast toast-bootstrap-compatibility-fix'
}),
```

Don't forget the original `toast` class.

Your (s)css file:

```
.toast-bootstrap-compatibility-fix {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with my issue

Answer (score 2):

i had this issue and i noticed that it was working but wasnt rendering the CSS properly, so then i checked the node_modules/toastr folder and realized that there were other CSS files, try including all the css files, because that worked for me.

add the css files in your angular.json file and try running yoru application again.

```
 "styles": [              
          "./src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "......",              
          "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr-old.css",
          "./src/styles.css",
          ".......",
          "......",
          "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
       ],
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to import

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

and add that under the @NgModule imports

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ......
  ],
  imports: [
     ......
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({ timeOut: 2000 enableHtml: true }),
  ],
  providers: [
    ToastService,
     ......
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for an easy solution
I just added the following line to global `styles.css`:

```
@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css'
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue again. The resources above said it was fixed but not for me. Even after getting the latest resources for both bootstrap and toastr. After much investigations I found that simply adding '!important' to the relevant toastr alert type backgrounds resolved this for me. See code below.

```
.toast-success{background-color:#51A351!important;}
.toast-error{background-color:#BD362F!important;}
.toast-info{background-color:#2F96B4!important;}
.toast-warning{background-color:#F89406!important;}
```

Although not good practice, I added the code the .min.css file. We do however host these files in our AWS CloudFront CDN and there is no need for duplicate CDN's.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have done to fix the problem is: by adding

```
 @import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';
```

into style.css - Main Style in root folder of your angular app

Answer (score 1):

I have imported
~ngx-toastr/toastr.css in my style.css of angular app
used

```
  @import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, non of these solutions helped. What I did in the end was to set this in the Angular.json for the production configuration:

```
    "extractCss": false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check the dependency.**

[image: ngx-toastr dependency]

**OR**

Try fixing the css import or

you can copy the css from here [toastr.css](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/HEAD/src/lib/toastr.css) and past it inside your global css or

create a new css file and add that file path in

angular.json -> styles: [..., "your/style/path/toastr.css"]

Answer (score 0):

For Angular - Material or any angular project we SHOULD need to import modules in sequence
like this in your app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
 ToastrModule.forRoot({
    timeOut: 3000,
    positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
    preventDuplicates: true,
    closeButton: true
 })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have imported ~ngx-toastr/toastr.css but it was not working. So, I have copied all the CSS present in the above file and pasted it in my styles.css.

It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

copying toastr.css code to my angular project styles.css file worked.

Comment: That's a bad solution, the styles need to be maintained manually.