# Angular 7 - Custom toastr not showing message

Tags: angular, notifications, angular7, toastr

I've created a custom toastr notification component like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Toast, ToastrService, ToastPackage } from "ngx-toastr";
import { trigger } from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: "app-ribbon",
  templateUrl: "./ribbon.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./ribbon.component.scss"],
  animations: [
    trigger("flyInOut", []),
  ]
})

export class RibbonComponent extends Toast {
  constructor( protected toastrService: ToastrService, public toastPackage: ToastPackage) {
    super(toastrService, toastPackage);
    }
  }
```

With it's own `css` styling. I've configured my `app.module` file like this:

```
 imports: [
      ToastrModule.forRoot({
        toastComponent: RibbonComponent,
      })]
```

And when I try to use the `toastr` service like this:

```
 showToaster() {
      this.toastr.success("Message Test");
  }
}
```

In another component it displays my component but with no message text at all, only the empty component

What's missing here?

Comment: Imported service name is "toastrService" but in showToaster() function you are using as "toastr" try change that to "toastrService"

Comment: that's not the problem, I've tried a lot I don't know why the message it's empty on my custom component

Comment: 1. Try Importing like this in your app.module `imports: [
      ToastrModule.forRoot()]` 2. Use `constructor( private toastrService: ToastrService,`)

Comment: But like that it will display the default toast component, I want to display my custom one

Comment: Can you post your scss and HTML file?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989445/ngx-toastr-toast-not-showing-in-angular-7#